# Create button search filters

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to take text from selected option or value from input field and create html element (div) and append it to .selected-filters div when I click on add filter button. Here is jsfieddle https://jsfiddle.net/bn4m9pyu/17/ . I want to append something like Author is Authorone, Author Is not Authortwo, or value from input like Author contain [input value]

```
<ul class="filters">
  <li class="submenu">
    <div class="filter">
      <span>Author</span>
    </div>
    <div class="details">
      <form>
        <div class="filter-option">
          <input type="radio" id="is" name="author" checked="checked"/>
          <label for="is">Is</label>
          <div class="searchFilter">
            <select class="selectpicker">
              <option value="authorone">Author one</option>
              <option value="authortwo">Author two</option>
              <option value="authorthree">Author three</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="filter-option">
          <input type="radio" id="isnot" name="author" checked="checked"/>
          <label for="isnot">Is not</label>
          <div class="searchFilter">
            <select class="selectpicker">
              <option value="authorone">Author one</option>
              <option value="authortwo">Author two</option>
              <option value="authorthree">Author three</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="filter-option">
          <input type="radio" id="contains" name="author" checked="checked"/>
          <label for="contains">Contains</label>
          <div class="searchFilter">
            <input type="text" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <div class="addFilter">
        Add Filter
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="submenu">
    <div class="filter">
      <span>Author</span>
    </div>
    <div class="details">
      <form>
        <div class="filter-option">
          <input type="radio" id="is" name="author" checked="checked"/>
          <label for="is">Is</label>
          <div class="searchFilter">
            <select class="selectpicker">
              <option value="authorone">Author one</option>
              <option value="authortwo">Author two</option>
              <option value="authorthree">Author three</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="filter-option">
          <input type="radio" id="isnot" name="author" checked="checked"/>
          <label for="isnot">Is not</label>
          <div class="searchFilter">
            <select class="selectpicker">
              <option value="authorone">Author one</option>
              <option value="authortwo">Author two</option>
              <option value="authorthree">Author three</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="filter-option">
          <input type="radio" id="contains" name="author" checked="checked"/>
          <label for="contains">Contains</label>
          <div class="searchFilter">
            <input type="text" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <div class="addFilter">
        Add Filter
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="selected-filters">
  Selected filters goes here
</div>
```

Comment: Have you looked at JQuery's :contains feature? -> https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `jquery`.

```
 1. Use the selector to find the selected radio button
 2. Find the parent for that radio button
 3. From there you can find the associated author
```

This could been approached in a cleaner way if you had organized your HTML for this purpose.

```js
$('.submenu .filter').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().find('.details').toggleClass('open');
});


$('.addFilter').on('click', function() {
  var radio = $(this).parent().find('input[type=radio]:checked');
  var label = $("label[for='" + $(radio).attr('id') + "']");
  var author = $(radio).parent().find('.searchFilter > input, .selectpicker').eq(0).val();
  var element = $(`<p>Author ${label.text()} ${author}</p>`);
  
  $('.selected-filter').append(element);
});
```

```css
li {
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: darkred;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.details {
  display: none;
}

.open {
  display: block;
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
}
.filter-option {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.addFilter {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid darkred;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: darkred;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="filters">
  <li class="submenu">
    <div class="filter">
      <span>Author</span>
    </div>
    <div class="details">
      <form>
        <div class="filter-option">
          <input type="radio" id="is_1" name="author" checked="checked"/>
          <label for="is_1">Is</label>
          <div class="searchFilter">
            <select class="selectpicker">
              <option value="authorone">Author one</option>
              <option value="authortwo">Author two</option>
              <option value="authorthree">Author three</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="filter-option">
          <input type="radio" id="isnot_1" name="author" checked="checked"/>
          <label for="isnot_1">Is not</label>
          <div class="searchFilter">
            <select class="selectpicker">
              <option value="authorone">Author one</option>
              <option value="authortwo">Author two</option>
              <option value="authorthree">Author three</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="filter-option">
          <input type="radio" id="contains_1" name="author" checked="checked"/>
          <label for="contains_1">Contains</label>
          <div class="searchFilter">
            <input type="text" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <div class="addFilter">
        Add Filter
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="submenu">
    <div class="filter">
      <span>Author</span>
    </div>
    <div class="details">
      <form>
        <div class="filter-option">
          <input type="radio" id="is" name="author" checked="checked"/>
          <label for="is">Is</label>
          <div class="searchFilter">
            <select class="selectpicker">
              <option value="authorone">Author one</option>
              <option value="authortwo">Author two</option>
              <option value="authorthree">Author three</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="filter-option">
          <input type="radio" id="isnot" name="author" checked="checked"/>
          <label for="isnot">Is not</label>
          <div class="searchFilter">
            <select class="selectpicker">
              <option value="authorone">Author one</option>
              <option value="authortwo">Author two</option>
              <option value="authorthree">Author three</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="filter-option">
          <input type="radio" id="contains" name="author" checked="checked"/>
          <label for="contains">Contains</label>
          <div class="searchFilter">
            <input type="text" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <div class="addFilter">
        Add Filter
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="selected-filter">
  Selected filters goe
</div>
```